# Why is the image not showing in my edit

Tags: support, edits, on-hold

Ok, I have edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756775/need-a-css-layout-like-the-image-attached-i-have-attached-the-code-i-am-using)

It was put on hold primarily because the OP had not posted any code to demonstrate what he had tried.
However the OP came back and posted a comment where he posted a link to a fiddle.

So I edited the question so as to include the code from the fiddle and include the image which the OP had originally pasted. Now my edit does not show the image but the link to the image is perfect.

[Here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAOty.png)

Also what is the further course of action on this as it was voted to be put on hold

**EDIT:** [My review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2912774) was approved but the Image is still not showing up

Comment: Regarding coming off hold; your edit will have put it in the reopen queue, you've done all you need to. Assuming people vote to reopen it will be reopened soon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have indented the line with 4 spaces, so it is treated as code, to be shown as is.

I have removed some of the spaces and all is well.

> Also what is the further course of action on this as it was voted to be put on hold

Do nothing. The approved edit will have put it on the reopen queue - if the changes have made it a good question, it should get reopened (or as you put it, off-hold).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Will this question be put off hold?

Comment: @MarsOne - It will end up in the reopen queue, if the changes are good, it will get reopened.